# SharePoint 2013 Document Library will not open in Explorer on 2008 server

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, sharepoint-2013

I have a site running SharePoint 2013 on Windows 2012. I can open the document library in IE, then in Windows Explorer from my Windows 7 machine. When I try to do the same from a Windows 2008 server with IE 9 I get a username/password prompt (when I try to Open With Explorer). This had worked at some point. The 2008 server has DesktopExperience installed and WebClient running. Any other ideas?

Comment: Browsing a Sharepoint 2010 document library via Windows Explorer works on this same machine.

Comment: I got my dev SharePoint 2013 to work by disabling UAC on the 2008 server. My prod SharePoint 2013 tells me "We're having a problem opening this location in File Explorer. Add this web site to your Trusted SItes list and try again". The site is already in my intranet zone.